# React Redux - mapstatetoprops and mapDispatchToProps not being called

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to React and Redux also. I'm struggling to find how it works with no clue.
Here's my store creation function:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers/reducers', () => {
      const nextReducer = rootReducer;
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }
  return store;
}
```

Here's my index.js with Provider:

```
const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Main}>
        <IndexRoute component={Intents}/>
        <Route path="/intents" component={Intents}/>
        <Route path="/intents/:intentId" component={Intent}/>
        <Route path="/entities" component={Entities}>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Calling connect() in Main component:

```
export class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
        <div>
          <div style={styles.container}>
            <Header/>
            <main style={styles.main}>
              {this.props.children}
            </main>
            <Footer/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

Main.propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.node
};
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  console.log(state);
  return {
    todos: state.todos
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(TodoActions, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Main);
```

But no matter what I try, mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are not called.

Comment: Do you have `Main` component rendered at page?

Comment: There is no problem with your code. How is declared your store? did `Main` renders?

Comment: can you show the entire code for Main and TodoActions. There is not problem with your current code.

Comment: I updated the question for more detail code. And my Main Component is rendered if you want to know.

Comment: How do you import `Main` in index.js?